# Single File Component with slot gets unexpectedly re-rendered on parent event

Tags: vue.js, vue-sfc

I am not very confortable with Vue slots yet so maybe I'm using them wrongly. I have 2 Single File Components that are defined the following way :

HelloWorld.vue :

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item"
      @mouseover="highlighted = item"
      :class="{ highlighted: highlighted === item }"
    >
      {{ item }}
      <Info>
        <img
          src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"
        />
      </Info>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Info from "./Info.vue";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    Info,
  },
  data: () => ({
    highlighted: null,
    items: [1, 2, 3],
  }),
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.highlighted {
  background: grey;
}
</style>
```

Info.vue :

```js
<template>
  <div><slot /></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Info",
  beforeUpdate() {
    console.log("beforeUpdate Info.vue");
  },
};
</script>
```

What I don't understand is : when the `mouseover` event in the `HelloWorld` SFC is triggered, the `beforeUpdate` method of `Info.vue` is called 3 times each time (as many times as there are items in my list). How come this method is called (since no data passed to the `Info` component is changed) and how can I prevent this potentially costly re-render? Interestingly, the re-render doesn't happen if I remove the `class` attribute in `HelloWorld` that toggles the line highlight.

The full code is here : https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-swanson-57oev

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `highlighted` class has to be evaluated for each element, every time mouseover event takes place.

This happens because `highlighted` prop changes every time mouseover takes place, which re-triggers Vue to figure out which element to attach the `highlighted` css class to.

Comment: I understand that the class has to be evaluated, but I don't undestand why all the element's content has to be evaluated as well. Also, what is my alternative here to prevent the re-render of the sub-component? Any documentation on this topic?